# CentOS Multilib version conflict

Tags: centos, yum, centos6.6

I'm trying to install HHVM on my CentOS 6.6, but this multilib problem is not letting me.

Upon running `yum upgrade`, I get this result.

```
root@invictus [~]# yum upgrade
Loaded plugins: fastestmirror
Setting up Upgrade Process
Loading mirror speeds from cached hostfile
 * aso: repo-uscentral.asonoc.com
 * base: centos.mirror.lstn.net
 * epel: fedora-epel.mirror.lstn.net
 * extras: repos.dfw.quadranet.com
 * rpmforge: mirror.nexcess.net
 * updates: repos.dfw.quadranet.com
Resolving Dependencies
--> Running transaction check
---> Package cpp.x86_64 0:4.4.7-11.el6 will be updated
---> Package cpp.x86_64 0:4.8.2-8.el6 will be an update
--> Processing Dependency: libmpc.so.2()(64bit) for package: cpp-4.8.2-8.el6.x86_64
---> Package curl.x86_64 0:7.19.7-40.el6_6.3 will be updated
---> Package curl.x86_64 0:7.29.0-4.el6 will be an update
---> Package gcc.x86_64 0:4.4.7-11.el6 will be updated
---> Package gcc.x86_64 0:4.8.2-8.el6 will be an update
---> Package gcc-c++.x86_64 0:4.4.7-11.el6 will be updated
---> Package gcc-c++.x86_64 0:4.8.2-8.el6 will be an update
---> Package gmp.x86_64 0:4.3.1-7.el6_2.2 will be updated
---> Package gmp.x86_64 1:4.3.2-4.el6 will be an update
---> Package libcurl.x86_64 0:7.19.7-40.el6_6.3 will be updated
---> Package libcurl.x86_64 0:7.29.0-4.el6 will be an update
---> Package libevent.x86_64 0:1.4.13-4.el6 will be updated
---> Package libevent.x86_64 0:1.4.14b-2.hphp.el6 will be an update
---> Package libgcc.x86_64 0:4.4.7-11.el6 will be updated
---> Package libgcc.x86_64 0:4.8.2-8.el6 will be an update
---> Package libgomp.x86_64 0:4.4.7-11.el6 will be updated
---> Package libgomp.x86_64 0:4.8.2-8.el6 will be an update
---> Package libstdc++.x86_64 0:4.4.7-11.el6 will be updated
---> Package libstdc++.x86_64 0:4.8.2-8.el6 will be an update
---> Package libstdc++-devel.x86_64 0:4.4.7-11.el6 will be updated
---> Package libstdc++-devel.x86_64 0:4.8.2-8.el6 will be an update
---> Package libtool.x86_64 0:2.2.6-15.5.el6 will be updated
---> Package libtool.x86_64 0:2.4.2-21.el6 will be an update
---> Package libtool-ltdl.x86_64 0:2.2.6-15.5.el6 will be updated
---> Package libtool-ltdl.x86_64 0:2.4.2-21.el6 will be an update
---> Package libtool-ltdl-devel.x86_64 0:2.2.6-15.5.el6 will be updated
---> Package libtool-ltdl-devel.x86_64 0:2.4.2-21.el6 will be an update
---> Package mpfr.x86_64 0:2.4.1-6.el6 will be updated
---> Package mpfr.x86_64 0:2.4.2-1.el6 will be an update
--> Running transaction check
---> Package libmpc.x86_64 0:0.8.3-0.3.svn855.el6 will be installed
--> Finished Dependency Resolution
Error:  Multilib version problems found. This often means that the root
       cause is something else and multilib version checking is just
       pointing out that there is a problem. Eg.:

         1. You have an upgrade for libgcc which is missing some
            dependency that another package requires. Yum is trying to
            solve this by installing an older version of libgcc of the
            different architecture. If you exclude the bad architecture
            yum will tell you what the root cause is (which package
            requires what). You can try redoing the upgrade with
            --exclude libgcc.otherarch ... this should give you an error
            message showing the root cause of the problem.

         2. You have multiple architectures of libgcc installed, but
            yum can only see an upgrade for one of those arcitectures.
            If you don't want/need both architectures anymore then you
            can remove the one with the missing update and everything
            will work.

         3. You have duplicate versions of libgcc installed already.
            You can use "yum check" to get yum show these errors.

       ...you can also use --setopt=protected_multilib=false to remove
       this checking, however this is almost never the correct thing to
       do as something else is very likely to go wrong (often causing
       much more problems).

       Protected multilib versions: libgcc-4.8.2-8.el6.x86_64 != libgcc-4.4.7-11.el6.i686
root@invictus [~]#
```

Upon running `yum check`

```
root@invictus [~]# yum check
Loaded plugins: fastestmirror
python-libs-2.6.6-52.el6.x86_64 has missing requires of libffi.so.5()(64bit)
Error: check all
root@invictus [~]#
```

Comment: What is that "aso" repo?

Comment: I'm not totally sure. I believe it came preinstalled on my CentOS server.

Comment: Oh, I'm silly. It's my host's repo. ASmallOrange.

Answer (score 2):

The problem is that there *is* no `libgcc.x86_64 0:4.8.2-8.el6` package in RHEL6/CentOS6. The current version for EL6 is 4.4.7-11, which is the version you currently have installed.

The task in front of you is to figure out why yum found such a package in the first place.

First, clean your yum cache completely. It's possible that someone built such a package by accident and it got pulled later, but your system still has metadata referring to it.

```
yum clean all
```

Second, figure out where yum *thinks* such a package is coming from. Run:

```
yum list all libgcc
```

On a clean CentOS 6.6 system you should get the following output:

```
Installed Packages
libgcc.x86_64                         4.4.7-11.el6                         @base
Available Packages
libgcc.i686                           4.4.7-11.el6                         base
```

If you get something else, the repository will be identified, and you can then disable that repo, contact its maintainer, suspect malicious activity, etc.

If you get identical output, then you should be able to continue with the system update.

Comment: I ran the code and got this back: http://prntscr.com/5m17ry - I want to install HHVM which uses the hop5 repo.

Comment: That repo is broken, and if you did manage to install it successfully, would likely break your system in obscure ways, possibly even leaving it unbootable. Interestingly, I also note that [the HHVM project recommend you do not use it](https://github.com/facebook/hhvm/wiki/Prebuilt-Packages-on-Centos-6.x) for other reasons. After doing some more looking around I learned that that repo is meant for Amazon Linux, not for EL6, which is why it won't work.

Answer (score 0):

I have similar problem. When I try update centos7 i get result:

```
Multilib version problems found. This often means that the root
cause is something else and multilib version checking is just
pointing out that there is a problem. Eg.:

  1. You have an upgrade for device-mapper-libs which is missing some
     dependency that another package requires. Yum is trying to
     solve this by installing an older version of device-mapper-libs of the
     different architecture. If you exclude the bad architecture
     yum will tell you what the root cause is (which package
     requires what). You can try redoing the upgrade with
     --exclude device-mapper-libs.otherarch ... this should give you an error
     message showing the root cause of the problem.

  2. You have multiple architectures of device-mapper-libs installed, but
     yum can only see an upgrade for one of those architectures.
     If you don't want/need both architectures anymore then you
     can remove the one with the missing update and everything
     will work.

  3. You have duplicate versions of device-mapper-libs installed already.
     You can use "yum check" to get yum show these errors.

...you can also use --setopt=protected_multilib=false to remove
this checking, however this is almost never the correct thing to
do as something else is very likely to go wrong (often causing
much more problems).

Chronione wersje multilib: 7:device-mapper-libs-1.02.135-1.el7_3.2.x86_64 != 7:device-mapper-libs-1.02.135-1.el7_3.1.i686
```

In my case I have problem with `device-mapper-libs`.
In first step check duplicate packages:

```
yum list --showduplicates device-mapper-libs-1.02.135-1.el7_3.1

Wczytane wtyczki: fastestmirror, langpacks Loading mirror speeds from
cached hostfile  * base: centos1.hti.pl  * epel: ftp.icm.edu.pl  *
extras: centos1.hti.pl  * nux-dextop: li.nux.ro  * updates:
ftp.icm.edu.pl  * webtatic: uk.repo.webtatic.com Zainstalowane pakiety
device-mapper-libs.i686                                               
7:1.02.135-1.el7_3.1                                                  
@updates device-mapper-libs.x86_64                                    
7:1.02.135-1.el7_3.1                                                  
@updates Dostępne pakiety device-mapper-libs.i686                     
7:1.02.135-1.el7_3.1                                                  
updates  device-mapper-libs.x86_64
```

Next remove invalid package:

```
yum erase device-mapper-libs.i686
```

And now execute update/upgrade.  It's worked.

Answer (score 0):

I have a similar problem when I was updating my system CentOS 7. The main problem is that the update process is pulling in some dependencies which are conflicting the version which are installed on the local machine. In order to be able to update a machine, one need to remove the older version of the packages which are conflicting i.e.

```
rpm -e --justdb --nodeps libgcc-4.4.7-11.el6.i686
```

Sometime it can be also a problem with 32 vs 64 packages which can be solved like [here](https://bugzilla.redhat.com/show_bug.cgi?id=1477574)